# Change ImageView image in code using JavaFX Scene Builder

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, scenebuilder

I'm trying to change the image in an ImageView component on button click. I need it to be a local image. I keep getting a path error and I can't use an ImageIcon and convert it to an Image. Is there not a simple way to do this?

```
package tictactoesimulator_alliebeckman;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

/**
 *
 * @author Allie
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    // my components        
    @FXML
    public Label lblWinLose;
    @FXML
    public Button btnNewGame;
    @FXML
    public ImageView ivOne;

    // Event handle for button click  
    @FXML
    public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

        // here is where I'm having the issue I have the image file in my src folder
        // I've tried using a ImageIcon and it wont convert to an Image?
        // All I need is the image to change to the local image on button click

        lblWinLose.setText("Clicked");
        Image image = new Image("o.png");
        ivOne = new ImageView(image);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }
}
```

The project layout can be seen in this Eclipse screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please can you post the Stack Trace

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the screenshot in your question, the image is in the same package as the `FXMLDocumentController` class.

The [`Image` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-) you are using is expecting the *string version of a URL* of the image: the best way to get such a URL is to use `getClass().getResource(...)` (as this will work whether you are loading from the file system or from a jar file). `getClass().getResource(...)` will resolve relative to the current class (or relative to the classpath if you begin the resource name with a leading `/`):

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("o.png").toExternalForm());
```

and then instead of creating a new `ImageView` you should do

```
ivOne.setImage(image);
```

Comment: If the file `o.png` is really in the root of the classpath, `new Image("o.png")` should work since what you manually do is already done in the `Image` constructor thx to [validateUrl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/scene/image/Image.java#1059)

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Good point. Probably more information is needed as to what is actually happening.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out. I tried both answers and it's still not working, I think maybe I have the images in the wrong folder?

Comment: @AllieMarie Ah, so your image there is in the same package as the class, not in the root of the classpath. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU!!